# Making an image from the list

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create an image from list of 1s and 0s in Python.

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open('Image1.gif') #the image is strictly black and white
img1_size = img1.size 
img1_k = []
for i in range(img1_size[0]): 
    for j in range(img1_size[1]): 
        tmp_pix = img1.getpixel((i,j))
        if (tmp_pix>127): 
            img1_k.append(1)
        else:
            img1_k.append(0)


img = Image.new('RGB', (img1_size[1],img1_size[0]), "white") 
cmap = {1: (255,255,255),
        0: (0,0,0)}
data = [cmap[i] for i in img1_k]
img.putdata(data)
img.show()             
img.save('Image2.png')
```

However, instead of original image:

[image]

The code produces rotated and inverted image:

[image]

I'm guessing that the format of putdata() differs from the way I acquired pixels for the list. How can I get the picture right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getpixel`, `putpixel` is based on x-y coordinates while `getdata`, `putdata` is based on row-column based.

First, you need to make the `img_k` row-column based:

```
for j in range(img1_size[1]):     # row (y)
    for i in range(img1_size[0]): # column (x)
        tmp_pix = img1.getpixel((i,j))
        if tmp_pix > 127:
            img1_k.append(1)
        else:
            img1_k.append(0)
```

Second, you need to create x*y sized image:

```
img = Image.new('RGB', (img1_size[0], img1_size[1]), "white")  # <--
# OR  Image.new('RGB', img1.size, "white") 
cmap = {1: (255,255,255),
        0: (0,0,0)}
data = [cmap[i] for i in img1_k]
img.putdata(data)
img.show()             
img.save('Image2.png')
```

---

BTW, instead of mixing `getpixel` and `putdata`, by using `getdata` and `putdata` the code can be simpler:

```
from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open('Image1.gif')
data = [(255, 255, 255) if pixel > 127 else (0, 0, 0) for pixel in img1.getdata()]
img = Image.new('RGB', img1.size, "white") 
img.putdata(data)
img.show()             
img.save('Image2.png')
```

Comment: @CaiphasKain, You're welcome. Happy Python programming.